# pine script trading - strategy does not trigger stop intraday

Tags: pine-script

Hello and thank you for looking into this!

I am backtesting a simple strategy which buys breakouts after short term pivot lows. I use the following code to enter and exit trades, once the condition for going long is met:

```
if long
    strategy.entry("Long", true, initial_qty, stop = entry_price, comment = "ELP")

strategy.exit(id = "Long", stop = stop_price1, limit = target_price1, comment = "Stop/TP")

if (barssince(change(strategy.opentrades)) == n_exit and time_stop)
    strategy.close("Long", comment = "timeout")
```

I want to trade this on the daily chart and the problem I have encounterd is that in almost all cases, the backtest ignores if the stop was hit intraday and shows a profit, if the TP is hit after that, or we open higher the next day (which is when my time stop would trigger). I have attached several pictures where the intraday PA hits the stop level and it does not trigger, as well as one example, where it hits and triggers. I have no idea what to do about this, but it obviously distorts the result of the backtest a lot.

[1st example](https://www.tradingview.com/x/BpA7i4Fu/)

[2nd example](https://www.tradingview.com/x/L1LzR5D3/)

[3rd example](https://www.tradingview.com/x/mqjVAuBh/)

[And here it worked](https://www.tradingview.com/x/FYg7J7MG/)

I am not using calc_on_order_fills or calc_on_every_tick. Have tried to change these, but they do not affect the problem.

Thank you so much for helping me on with this, I am quite new to Pine Script, as well as to this board ;-)

Comment: Maybe this https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Strategies.html?highlight=strategy#broker-emulator can push your thoughts to right direction.

Comment: Thank you Andrey! It must be because of 
1. If the bar’s high is closer to bar’s open than the bar’s low, the broker emulator assumes that intrabar price was moving this way: open → high → low → close.
2. If the bar’s low is closer to bar’s open than the bar’s high, the broker emulator assumes that intrabar price was moving this way: open → low → high → close.
Now how to figure out a way to still get a valid backtest...;-)